# Sequences in $L_2$ space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $M$ be compact metric space, with finite full measure $\mu.$ Let $\epsilon:M\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Assume that $\epsilon>0$ in $M\setminus \{p_0\}$ for some $p_0\in M$ and $\epsilon(p_0)=0.$ Consider a sequence of measurable functions $f_n$ in $L_2(M,\mu)$ with the property 
$$\int\limits_{M} \epsilon(p)|f_n(p)-f_m(p)|^2\,dp\to 0\,\,\, \text{as}\,\,
n,m\to\infty$$
and $f_n$ converges to $0$ in $L_1(M,\mu).$ 
Let $g:M\to \mathbb{C}$ be a function such that 
$$\int\limits_{M} \epsilon(p)|f_n(p)-g(p)|^2\,dp\to 0\,\,\, \text{as}
n\to\infty.$$
Can we conclude that $g=0$ in $L_2(M,\mu)?$

Comment: With Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, consider the sequence $(f_n)$ where $f_n=\sqrt n\chi_{[0,1/n]}$.

Comment: Note that in David's nice example, $f_n$ is not Cauchy. If you assume the existence of $g$ s.t. $f_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^2$, then by finiteness of $\mu$, $L^2 \subset L^1$ and $f_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^1$. Then, by uniqueness of limits up to equivalence class, $g = 0$ a.e. I'm not sure how to remedy the situation with the presence of $\epsilon(p)$, I'm a little worried about convergence around $p_0$ depending on the decay rate of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Dear Snarski. Thank you for comment. That was a problem for me as well :)